# Shell script condition refactoring

Tags: bash, shell, refactoring

How can I refactoring the next lines to join to conditions in one with OR operator?

```sh
if [[ "$lexer_date" > "$lexer_ts_date" ]]; then
    generate_grammar
elif [[ "$parser_date" > "$parser_ts_date" ]]; then
    generate_grammar
fi
```

Something like this:

```sh
if lexer_date > lexer_ts_date or parser_date > parser_ts_date: generate_grammar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `or` operator is `||`

```
if [[ "$lexer_date" > "$lexer_ts_date" || "$parser_date" > "$parser_ts_date" ]]; then
    generate_grammar
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

or

```
((lexer_date>lexer_ts_date|parser_date>parser_ts_date)) && generate_grammar
```

Test script:

```
$ cat test
#!/bin/bash

lexer_date=2
lexer_ts_date=1
parser_date=2
parser_ts_date=1

generate_grammar(){ echo ok; }

((lexer_date>lexer_ts_date|parser_date>parser_ts_date)) && generate_grammar
```

Testing:

```
$ ./test
ok
```

Comment: Return me an error: `scripts/grammar.sh: line 28: ((: 2021-02-11 13:21:40: syntax error in expression (error token is "13:21:40")`